# Django: Trouble filtering my Artist model to show objects from the request user

Tags: django, django-models

So I have a model in a different app that records a user's 5 favorite artists. The model is uses the user as a foreign key through my own custom userprofile model. So I want to display the list of favourite artists linked to the request profile when I log in and I want to display it. But im having trouble filtering it because I keep getting an error saying the request user needs to be a userprofile instance.
Heres my music model

```
    from django.db import models
from accounts.models import UserProfile

# Create your models here.
class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200)
    artist_name2 = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200)
    artist_name3 = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200)
    artist_name4 = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200)
    artist_name5 = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    as_pro = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='artist')


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.as_pro}-{'Artist List'}"
```

and heres my profile view in the accounts app

```
def profile(request):
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    obj = Artist.objects.filter(as_pro=request.user)


    context = {
        'userprofile': UserProfile,
        'obj' : obj,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', context)
```

heres also my profile template where I want to display it but like I said I'm finding it hard to crack why I cant display a simple list.

```
                    </div>
                    
                      <p>{{ obj.artist_name }}</p>
                      <p>{{ obj.artist_name2 }}</p>
                      <p>{{ obj.artist_name3 }}</p>
                      <p>{{ obj.artist_name4 }}</p>
                    
                    
    
                </div>
```

Comment: I believe you simply forget to use the User Profile instance you got, change `Artist.objects.filter(as_pro=request.user)` to `Artist.objects.filter(as_pro=userprofile)`. Note also `userprofile.artist` would directly get you the artist instance instead of writing the query. Something similar can also be done for the user profile from the user instance.

Comment: Thanks for the templates tip if it wasn't for that I'd still be clueless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
objs = Artist.objects.filter(as_pro__user=request.user)
```

or if you need the `UserProfile` of the logged in user anyway, you can work with:

```
userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
obj = Artist.objects.filter(as_pro=userprofile)
```